# Cannot make substitution

Tags: tipa, substitution

I want a command `\myreplace` replacing all instances of `:` with the `\textlengthmark` command from the `tipa` package. (In fact, this is one of the things that the `tipa` command `\textipa` does, but for reasons unrelated to this matter, I cannot use that particular command.) Therefore, I run the code.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xstring,tipa}

\newcommand*\myreplace[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{:}{\textlengthmark}}

\begin{document}

\myreplace{gaga:}

\end{document}
```

However, all I get is

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] \myreplace{gaga:}

This seems related to the `\textlengthmark` command, since replacing it with any other string works just fine.

Can somebody find the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the usual issue about `xstring` that by default tries to do full expansion of its arguments.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xstring,tipa}

\newcommand*\myreplace[1]{%
  \saveexpandmode\noexpandarg
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{:}{\textlengthmark}%
  \restoreexpandmode}

\begin{document}

\myreplace{gaga:}

\end{document}
```

If you don't need applications of `xstring` commands with different settings of the “expand mode”, just issue `\noexpandarg` after `\usepackage{xstring}` and forget about it, as your version will work.

Answer (score 1):

A `stringstrings` approach:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{stringstrings,tipa}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\myreplace[1]{%
  \encodetoken{\textlengthmark}%
  \convertchar[e]{#1}{:}{\textlengthmark}%
  \retokenize{\thestring}%
  \protected@edef\xyz{\thestring}%
  \decodetoken{\textlengthmark}%
  \xyz
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\myreplace{gaga:} 
\end{document}
```